# Redirect subdomain from non-www to www with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I'm trying to redirect http://subdomain.domain.com to http://www.subdomain.domain.com. I've manage my self to make the domain redirection work but i can't make my subdomain work. Does anyone have a clue? It has to be done with .htacces!

Thanks and sorry disturbing.

Comment: I posted an answer bellow, if you are happy with the answer ,please accept it otherwise let me know how I can improve it.

Comment: I answered u on a comment. Hope we can figure out whats wrong. Thanks!!

Comment: Reload the page to see my reply under my ans.

Comment: I did! I also answered u back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

#subdomain non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```

Replace **sub.domain.com** with your subdomain in the pattern of first condition.

This will redirect

```
http://sub.domain.com
```

to

```
http://www.sub.domain.com
```

Comment: It's not working, my .htaccess file looks like this:

`RewriteEngine On

# rule for forcing www on domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#subdomain non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^producte.a14aargomhan.ga$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]

DirectoryIndex portada-productos-ausias.html index.html index.php`

Comment: my .htacces file is in the domain, do i have to put this on the subdomain .htacess file? Thanks!

Comment: If you subdomain is pointin to the folder, try putting it in that folder.

Comment: Btw, the rule I posted is ok, It works fine on my apache

Comment: Try to access my subdomain, it doesn't seem to work. In any case, if that is the solution, ill post it as correct and try to talk with the hosting manager. Thanks!

Comment: Dona! I was putting the condition on the domain .htaccess file instead of the sub.domain .htaccess file! Thanks starkeen!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this programmatically with a redirect:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://www.subdomain.domain.com'" />
```

(the content=0 means don't wait, redirect immediately)

Or you can do this at the domain name level. If you have control over domain.com's DNS entry, you can add an alias so that typing the first domain name actually sends it to the 2nd, then you don't have to worry about doing this in code. With all the different providers and tools, it's impractical to try to explain how to do that, but the site's customer service (or FAQs) would likely have instructions to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I actually need to redirect it through .htacces. Forgot to mention at the question. I'll correct the question. Thanks again.

Comment: Take a look at [this link on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess), I'm not sure a redirect can be done with htaccess, although it can do url rewrites... not the same thing though.

Comment: Yeah, rewrites will do! I meant rewrite condition. Thanks anyway!